# How to avoid unwanted connections to the Azure master database using mobile services?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

The following code:

```
    private void IsolateIssue()
    {
        using (var context = new SomeName.Models.MobileServiceContext())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
            var numberOfItems = context.TodoItems.Count();
        }
    }
```

results in an error (when calling var numberOfItems):

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'SomeLoginName'.

This is my connectionString:

> "Data Source=ServerName.database.windows.net;Initial
>   Catalog=SomeDataBaseName;User
>   ID=SomeLoginName;Password=SomePassword};Asynchronous
>   Processing=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"

It is obvious that it can not connect to the master database. Given the username and password, I also cannot connect to the master database with LinqPad (when I try I get a similar error). However, it should not connect at all to the master database. When I try to login on SomeDataBaseName with Linqpad, I succeed in getting the number of todoItems (17). This proves that there is no need to access the master database at all for the given purpose.

First, I have to make sure I can get the number of items in my mobile service. How do I do that? The initial Catalog shows that it should connect to SomeDataBaseName and there is no need to connect to the master database to get the number of items. How do I avoid that it tries to do so?

In case it helps, here is the stacktrace:

> StackTrace    "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass34.<UsingConnection>b__32()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DropDatabase(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, String databaseName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbDeleteDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.DeleteDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteDatabase()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Delete(ObjectContext objectContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)\r\n

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope?

Comment: When I search in my project on "TransactionScope", I do not get any results. So that probably means : "No".

Comment: Is it stupid not to use TransactionScope? If I would create a new database and do all transactions within a TransactionScope, will it become likely that this kind of issues do not appear anymore?

Comment: No, I just saw the word "Enlist" on the stack. That often indicates distributed transactions. TS is prone to cause them by accident. I have no idea what causes the problem you are facing. I'd look into EF source code, follow the stack from the exception and find out why EF is explicitly referencing [master]. Log a bug, the team is very responsive.

Answer (score 2):

I see this in your stack: `System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. I believe that EF needs access to the master database in order to drop and recreate your database.

This blog post mentions the `ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges` initializer, which may do what you want: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/07/fresh-updates-to-azure-mobile-services-net.aspx